# Zipping dynamic files in App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zip

Is there anyway I can zip dynamically generated content, such as a freshly rendered html template, into a zip file using zipfile?

There seem to be some examples around for zipping static content, but none for zipping dynamic ones. Or, is it not possible at all?

One more question: Is it possible to create a zip file with a bunch of sub-folders inside it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add whatever you want to a zip file using [`ZipFile.writestr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr):

```
my_data = "<html><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>"
z.writestr("hello.html", my_data)
```

You can also use sub-folders using `/` (or `os.sep`) as a separator:

```
z.writestr("site/foo/hello/index.html", my_data)
```

Answer (score 14):

The working code: (for app engine:)

```
output = StringIO.StringIO()
z = zipfile.ZipFile(output,'w')
my_data = "<html><body><p>Hello, world!</p></body></html>"
z.writestr("hello.html", my_data)
z.close()

self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/x-zip"
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.zip"
self.response.out.write(output.getvalue())
```

Thanks again to Schnouki and Ryan.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Schnouki's excellent answer, you can also pass ZipFile a file-like object, such as one created by [StringIO.StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html).

Comment: If you're using Python 3, it needs to be io.BytesIO (StringIO module is gone, and zipfile expects a bytes buffer)

Comment: Oops, just realized that this is about App Engine. You should probably ignore my last comment :), sorry.