# Zip a set of blobs from appengine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zip

I need to zip a set of blobs available in data store.
These can of different types like some html/images/swf/ etc.
where all these are available in datastore as blob.

I tried to implement this solution:
[Zipping dynamic files in App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963800/zipping-dynamic-files-in-app-engine-python)?

Tried with some static texts it worked great, I am also able to create a zip with a set of files with respective content but I could not trace out some issue when making zip from query.

```
z.writestr(fil.Template_name, my_data.encode('UTF-8'))
File "C:\Python25\lib\zipfile.py", line 626, in writestr
self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader())
File "C:\Python25\lib\zipfile.py", line 260, in FileHeader
return header + self.filename + extra
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xde in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the error for this part of code

```
       class filesDB(db.model) 
                   Template_file = db.BlobProperty()
                   Template_name= db.StringProperty()


       output = StringIO.StringIO()
       z = zipfile.ZipFile(output,'w')
       files =  filesDB.all().filter("fCreatedBy","sandeep")
       for fil in files:
        my_data = fil.Template_file
        z.writestr(fil.Template_name, my_data)
        z.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) documentation:

> There is no official file name encoding for ZIP files.
>   If you have unicode file names, you must convert them to byte strings in your desired encoding before passing them to write().

Try to encode your filename in UTF-8 for example with:

```
class filesDB(db.model) 
                   Template_file = db.BlobProperty()
                   Template_name= db.StringProperty()


       output = StringIO.StringIO()
       z = zipfile.ZipFile(output,'w')
       files =  filesDB.all().filter("fCreatedBy","sandeep")
       for fil in files:
        my_data = fil.Template_file
        z.writestr(fil.Template_name.encode('utf-8'), my_data)
        z.close()
```